# Orbeon Forms on iPhone and Android

Tags: ios, iphone, orbeon, xforms

I am new to Orbeon Forms / XForms. I am looking to develop an dynamic framework to generate forms on the fly and integrate into my application running on web & mobile devices. I can understand things on Web. But i wonder the scope of Orbeon form on iPhone / Android devices. Also if there is any online example for Orbeon or XForms which i can test on iPhone & Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Orbeon Forms is purely a web application. You can access it from iOS/Android using the browser, but it doesn't come with a native application. For more on this see, RFE [#1221](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1221) and [#1545](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1545).